# ADD @url.action with parameter on Table cell in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to this and I want to add a action method on table cell. The problem is Table is generated by java-script(AJAX).
Here's code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "GetData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (obj) {
                debugger;
                $tbl.empty();
                $tbl.append('<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Executed Date</th><th>Status</th></tr>');
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    $tbl.append(' <tr><td> <a href="#">' + obj[i].senderId + '</a></td><td>' + obj[i].subject + '</td><td>' + obj[i].msg + '</td><td>TESTING</td></tr>');
                }
            }
        });
```

Now instead of `<a href="#">` I want to add Action Method `@URL.Action` on that `<td>`. Here's my Action Method:

```
<a href=@Url.Action("SingleSentShow","Home", new { msgId ='+obj[i].senderId+',receiverId='+obj[i].senderId+ })>
```

But it shows error, I can't use javascript variable `obj[i].senderId` with c# code `@Url.Action("SingleSentShow","Home", new { msgId ='+obj[i].senderId+'...`
How can I fix this, or is there any other solution to add link or onClick on Table cell and pass data with it ?

Comment: I call function "GetData" through script. this function return data in "obj", `success: function (obj)`, Now i use this `obj` object and make a table using for loop. I want to move to another View when user click any row of 1st column. for that I can simply add `<a href="#">` on that `<td>` but i also need to send data with it. As far as I know to send data onclick `@url.Action` is used like `<a href=@Url.Action("SingleSentShow","Home", new { msgId ='+obj[i].senderId+',receiverId='+obj[i].senderId+ })>` Here `SingleSentShow` is a function in `Home` controller where I need to pass data...

Comment: How can I add this @URL.Action in `<td>` or simply I need to replace `<a href="#">` with this `<a href=@Url.Action("SingleSentShow",...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David is right, but a simplified way for easy understanding.

```
var href = @Url.Action("SingleSentShow","Home", new { msgId ="__msgID__" ,receiverId="__receiverID__" });
href = href.replace("__mgsID__",obj[i].senderId).replace("__receiverID__",obj[i].senderId);
$tbl.append(' <tr><td> <a href="' + href + '">' + '... the rest of your line');
```

Both will work fine.

Update: As per Comment.

Move the value of href to data-href and set href to # and add a new class for script to work. And when the link is clicked we can swap the values.

```
   $tbl.append(' <tr><td> <a href=# class=Test data-href="' + href + '">' + '... the rest of your line');
```

And add the below script.

```
   $(document).on('click', '.Test', function () {       
      $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('data-href'));
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem the data that I am passing is showing in URL !!! isn't there any other way ?

Comment: @Junaidumar so the link in tbl - /Home/SingleSentShow?msgID=***&receiverID=***. You don't want to show this link ?

Comment: @Junaidumar have updated the answer with comment you asked. Have a look and accept the answer.

Comment: Yes I don't want to show link, i'll test your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix server-side code and client-side code like that.

One option might be to put the base action URL in a JavaScript variable, and then append your query string parameters to it in JavaScript code.  Something like this:

```
var singleSentShowURL = '@Url.Action("SingleSentShow","Home")';
```

This would result in something like this client-side:

```
var singleSentShowURL = '/Home/SingleSentShow';
```

Then in your loop you could use that variable to manually build the URL.  Something like this:

```
$tbl.append(' <tr><td> <a href="' + singleSentShow + "?msgId=" + obj[i].senderId + "&receiverId=" + obj[i].senderId + '">' + '... the rest of your line');
```

You might split it into multiple lines for readability:

```
var href = singleSentShow + "?msgId=" + obj[i].senderId + "&receiverId=" + obj[i].senderId;
$tbl.append(' <tr><td> <a href="' + href + '">' + '... the rest of your line');
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks Its working, But there's a problem the data that I am passing is showing in URL !!!

Comment: @Junaidumar: Yes, that's how you supply data in a GET request.